# Get document properties.Keys value

Tags: 2010, powershell, managed-metadata, document, properties

I'm iterating all lists in a site collection trying to get all metadata, their values and eventually count them. I'm not so far yet, but I'm stuck in getting the values from a documents (file) property corresponding keys.

```
function GetAllFields($url)
{
    $sites = Get-SPSite $url

    foreach ($web in $sites.AllWebs)
    {
        $lists = $web.Lists

        foreach ($list in $lists)
        {
            if ($list.Title -like "*Document*")
            {
                $propertyExist = $false

                foreach ($field in $list.Fields)
                {
                    if ($field.Title -eq "Property Bag")
                    {
                        $propertyExist = $true
                    }
                }

                if ($propertyExist)
                {
                    Write-Host $web.Name -ForegroundColor Green
                    Write-Host "  " $list.Title -ForegroundColor Cyan

                    foreach ($item in $list.Items)
                    {
                        Write-Host "    " $item.Name

                        $file = $item.File

                        foreach ($key in $file.Properties.Keys)
                        {
                            Write-Host "      " $key -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
                            Write-Host "      " $file[$key] -ForegroundColor White
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    If ($sites -ne $null)
    {
        $sites.Dispose();
    }

    If ($web -ne $null)
    {
        $web.Dispose();
    }

}

GetAllFields http://portal
```

Everythings run nicely until I try to get the property value corresponding to the property key at this line:

```
Write-Host "      " $file[$key] -ForegroundColor White
```

A few good hours of searching hasn't made things clearer too me. How do I **get document properties.Keys value**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key's value should be in `$file.Properties[$key]`

**Update:** Output has been added

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but I still get no values in return. Not even vti_author is filled in as you cen see from my [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/822406/docprops.PNG)

Comment: @BennySkogberg Well, but based on my testing it works. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J1R0A.png

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev I must be doing something wrong further up the chain, then. That's strange :-S

Comment: I have simplified your code. Try this paste http://pastebin.com/g6TBpe10

Comment: @FalakMahmood Thanks! And I tried in a different environment this morning - it actually did work. I'll try not to doubt you again ;-)